Show that $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{x^m}{\sin^n x}dx$ is convergent if and only if $n < 1 + m.$
Show that $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{x^m}{\sin^n x}dx$ is convergent if and only if $n < 1 + m.$
The solution given in the book is as follows:
Let the given integral be $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}f(x)dx.$
If $m - n\geq  0,$ it is a proper integral since $\lim ( \frac{\sin x}{x})^n = 1.$
If $m-n < 0,$ then $0$ is the only point of infinite discontinuity of  $f(x).$
$f(x)\gt 0$ for all $x\in (0,\frac{\pi}{2})$ for all $x\in (0,\frac{\pi}{2}).$
$f(x)\gt 0,x\in (0,\frac{\pi}{2}].$
$\lim_{x\to 0+}x^{n-m}f(x) = 1,$ a
non-zero finite number).
By $\mu$ test $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}f(x)dx$ is convergent if and only if $n - m < 1,$ i.e if and only if $n < 1 + m.$
Therefore the given is convergent if and only if $n < 1 + m.$

However,I'm having some problems while understanding the solution.

Problem 1:


If $m - n\geq  0,$ it is a proper integral since $\lim ( \frac{\sin x}{x})^n = 1.$

How did they write this?
Of course the integral is proper since $f(x)$ is bounded on $(0,\frac{\pi}{2}].$ I also proved that $f(x)$ is bounded using the fact that $\lim ( \frac{\sin x}{x})^n = 1.$ But that required a lot of work for, first I drew the conclusion that $\lim ( \frac{\sin x}{x})^n = 1$ implies that there must exist a $\delta-$ neighborhood of $0$ where $0\lt f(x)\lt 2$ (, on choosing $\epsilon=1$).
Next, I examined the function $\frac{x^m}{\sin n^x}$ over the interval $[\delta,\frac{\pi}{2})$ since we proved that $f(x)$ is bounded in $(0,\delta).$ And again, I had to use many inequalities to show $f$ is bounded on $[\delta,\frac{\pi}{2}).$
So, a lot of work was involved in making this point.
But the way, the conclusion is mentioned in the solution, makes me wonder if there is an alternative and simpler way by which I can say, $f$ is bounded just from seeing that $\lim ( \frac{\sin x}{x})^n = 1$ holds? This will save me a lot of work in solving more such problems like this.
Any help regarding this issue will be greatly appreciated.

Problem 2:

I think there was no reason to consoder 2 cases. The case $m-n\geq 0$ was indeed unnecessary and we can just proceed with the proof done in the case $m-n\lt 0$. The proof given for that case simply works irrespective of the case.
Am I correct?

For 1, try limit comparsion test with $x^{m-n}$.

For your integral
$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{x^m}{\sin^n x}{\rm d}x,$$
$\pi/2$ is a "good" point for any $m,n\in\mathbb R$.
And for $0$, note that
$$\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{\frac{x^m}{\sin^n x}}{\frac1{x^{n-m}}}
=1,$$
and $$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{{\rm d}x}{x^{n-m}}$$
is convergent or is proper integral if and only if $n-m<1$.
So $$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{x^m}{\sin^n x}{\rm d}x,$$
is convergent or is proper integral if and only if $n-m<1$.


Actually, when $n-m\leq0$, your integral
$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{x^m}{\sin^n x}{\rm d}x$$
is proper integral, and when $n-m>0$, the integral is improper integral. In this case, the integral is convergent if and only if $0<n-m<1$.


